# BuddyPress redirecting to home page on login

Tags: buddypress, wp-redirect

I have two sites ([towermix.com](http://towermix.com) and [beta.towermix.com](http://beta.towermix.com)) running BuddyPress and both are doing the same thing.  When a site admin (or contributor or author) logs in using the WordPress login page, they are redirected to the home page instead of Dashboard.  I don't have any direction plugins on these sites.

How do I make it stop doing this?

I've tried the following:

- Deactivating plugins one-at-a-time and logging in afterwards. No change until I deactivated BuddyPress.
- Searched BuddyPress documentation and code - couldn't find any redirect code sending the user to the home page (unless the BP user account is being deleted)
- Replaced BuddyPress install with files downloaded from BP site - no change
- Replaced WordPress install with files downloaded from WP site - no change

Answer (score 1):

```
remove_filter( 'login_redirect', 'bp_core_login_redirect' );
```

If you place this in your functions.php the default login redirect from WordPress is used. So if you go to /wp-admin/ then you will be redirected to /wp-admin/.

Answer (score 0):

That is built-in to BuddyPress, the idea being that the majority of users aren't supposed to be in the admin panel.

The below thread has a function to redirect to the profile page, I'm sure it can be modded to go to the admin panel

[redirect to profile page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29545/login-redirect-to-certain-bp-profile-page)

Comment: While I can understand that the majority of users aren't supposed to be in the admin panel, the admins are.  Isn't there some kind of capability check before forwarding people? If you can admin the site, you should be allowed to go through to Dashboard, otherwise send them to the Buddypress pages.  I shouldn't have to modify the default behavior of BuddyPress for this.

Comment: my understanding is that there isn't. its an extra step, yes, but like any default there is bound to be those whom it is the opposite of what they want.